# can we use "continuous tenses" with the verb "get" when expressing illness?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In the dictionary,

> **[get](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get)** [transitive, no passive] **get something** to become infected with an illness; to suffer from a pain, etc.
>
> *I got this cold off (= from) you!*
>
> *She gets (= often suffers from) really bad headaches.*

---

> **[have](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have_1?q=have)** (also have got) have something (**not used in the progressive tenses**) to suffer from an illness or a disease
>
> *I've got a headache.*

---

So, we know that if we want to express our current  illness that is happening, we have to use the simple present tense with the verb "**have**"

So, we say "**I have a cold now**" but not "**I am having a cold**" (wrong)

But what about the verb "**get**"

can we say "I am getting a cold"?

[The Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20am%20getting%20a%20cold%2CI%20get%20a%20cold%2CI%20am%20having%20a%20cold%2C%20I%20have%20a%20cold&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20getting%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20get%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20a%20cold%3B%2Cc0) showed that people do say

- "**I have a cold**" (a lot of people say this)
- "**I get a cold**" (some people say this)
- "**I am getting a cold**" (few people say this)
- "**I am having a cold**" (no data found, maybe no one says this)

Can we use "continuous tenses" with the verb "**get**" when expressing illness?

Also, 1 more question, does the rule apply to other physical conditions such as **hiccup**, etc

For example, which of the following are **correct** when we want to express that a person is experiencing hiccups (it is happening now):

- "**I have hiccups**"
- "**I get hiccups**"
- "**I am getting hiccups**"
- "**I am having hiccups**"

Answer (score 1):

To me, "I am getting a cold" would mean "I have symptoms that make me think a cold is starting".

*Get* in this context means *catch a cold* or *start an attack of hiccups*. You might say "I get hiccups when I eat too fast", but you would not use *get* while you are currently having hiccups.